# Umbraco 7. Can't leave numeric field empty

Tags: umbraco

I am correctly upgrading a version 6.0.5 umbraco instance to version 7. The install seems to have been successful and all database changes seem to have completed as planned. However when trying to save a content node which contains a not required numeric field with no content supplied in the field, it fails to save with a validation error stating "The value is not a valid integer".

Has anyone else found this issue and a way to fix it as it's stopping me proceeding with the upgrade?

Thank you in advance

Dave

Comment: If you create a new document type with a not-required numeric field, do you get the same problem? Would be interesting to see if this affects new doc types or just the existing ones you upgraded.

Comment: I get the same problem with newly created document types in Umbraco 7 RC.  This is with a completely fresh install of the 7 RC, not an upgrade

Comment: @christofr I get this with new document types and old ones. They all have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This has been added as a confirmed issue after other people could replicate it.

See [my Umbraco forum post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/46439-Umbraco-7-numeric-fields-cant-be-empty?p=0#comment166569) here.

Umbraco issue details available [here](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-3728)

Thank you for the help

Dave